# How to replace blank strings with NA?

Tags: r

I would like to change blanks (no value) to missing (`NA`). I assumed this happens automatically when R read data (csv in my case), but there are just blanks so I tried:

```
is.na(data) <- data==""
```

I also tried:

```
data <- read.table("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings="")
data[data==""] <- NA
```

But blanks remain. How can I solve this?

Comment: It works on the example data I created.  Without an example using `dput`, it is hard to know the problem.

Comment: That seems to work just fine for `data<-c("ok","","good")` then running `is.na(data) <- data==""` works. are you sure that's a problem? Maybe your "blanks" are spaces?

Comment: @HiThere You could use `na.strings=''` in `read.csv`

Comment: Can you provide `dput(data)` after you reading it?

Comment: @David the data set has 9000obs. I´m not sure how to provide      dput(data) @ Richard, that has been done. I have that issue for the first time.

Comment: @HiThere You could `dput(head(data, 10))` if it has the `''` part

Comment: Try `dput(head(data, 100))`

Comment: `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show that the code works:

```
data <- data.frame( col1= c("", letters[1:4]), col2=c(letters[1:4], ""))
 is.na(data) <- data==''
 data
 #  col1 col2
 #1 <NA>    a
 #2   a    b
 #3    b    c
 #4    c    d
 #5    d <NA>
```

Suppose, if you have `''` along with spaces `'  '`, this won't work

```
 data <- data.frame( col1= c("", letters[1:4]), col2=c(letters[1:4], " "))
 data1 <- data
 is.na(data) <- data==''
  data
  col1 col2
 #1 <NA>    a
 #2    a    b
 #3    b    c
 #4    c    d
 #5    d
```

In such cases, you could use `str_trim`

```
  library(stringr)
  data1[] <- lapply(data1, str_trim)
  is.na(data1) <- data1==''
  data1
  #  col1 col2
  #1 <NA>    a
  #2    a    b
  #3    b    c
  #4    c    d
  #5    d <NA>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
x <- c("a", "", "b", "", "1")
x
x[x==""] <- NA
x
```

The results:

```
[1] "a" NA  "b" NA  "1"
```

Comment: i used a sample data. your command works just fine. however the original data is just stuck.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `na.strings = ""` when reading the data, for example

```
test1 <- data.frame(A = 1:6, B = c("6","7", "",3, "","7")) # Assuming this is your data
test1
#   A B
# 1 1 6
# 2 2 7
# 3 3  
# 4 4 3
# 5 5  
# 6 6 7

tf <- tempfile() # Creating some temp file for illustration
write.csv(test1, tf, row.names = F) # Saving the dummy data on the hard disk
read.csv(tf, na.strings = "") # Reading it back while specifying na.strings = ""
#   A  B
# 1 1  6
# 2 2  7
# 3 3 NA
# 4 4  3
# 5 5 NA
# 6 6  7
```